# L-BFGS-B optimization near the boundary resulting in error

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to find the parameters which maximize a function. I'll spare the details of the function -- seems irrelevant for the question. Suffice to say that it outputs finite values for finite input.

There are two parameters: the first with boundary `]inf, inf[`, the second with `[0.1, 0.9]`. Occasionally, depending on input `x`, optimization will fail with `non-finite value supplied by optim`.

This is the function call:

```
optim(par = par.init, fn = logL, method = 'L-BFGS-B',
                 lower = ll, upper = ul,
                 control = list('fnscale' = -1,
                                'parscale' = parscale, 
                                'trace' = 6))
```

Here is a `trace = 6` for such a failure with `fn(x) = ...` printout of the function value during optimization:

```
N = 2, M = 5 machine precision = 2.22045e-16
L = -inf 0.1 
X0 = -97.6214 0.7 
U = inf 0.9 
At X0, 0 variables are exactly at the bounds
fn(x) = -1011.16577103922
fn(x) = -1011.16572384272
fn(x) = -1011.16581824237
fn(x) = -1011.1648747304
fn(x) = -1011.1666763993
At iterate     0  f=       1011.2  |proj g|=          0.2
Iteration     0

---------------- CAUCHY entered-------------------

There are 1  breakpoints

Piece      1 f1, f2 at start point -8.1373e-01  8.1373e-01
Distance to the next break point =   2.2202e-01
Distance to the stationary point =   1.0000e+00
Variable  2  is fixed.

GCP found in this segment
Piece      2 f1, f2 at start point -1.7332e-03  2.2278e-03
Distance to the stationary point =   7.7798e-01
Cauchy X =  -97.5742 0.9 

---------------- exit CAUCHY----------------------

1  variables are free at GCP on iteration 1
fn(x) = -1011.28102186328
fn(x) = -1011.28100800724
fn(x) = -1011.28103572528
fn(x) = -1011.28102186328
fn(x) = -1011.27981205432
fn(x) = -1011.1379847835
fn(x) = -1011.1379461867
fn(x) = -1011.1380233868
fn(x) = -1011.13773152083
fn(x) = -1011.13825682889
LINE SEARCH 1 times; norm of step = 0.0454532
X = -97.6109 0.744238 
G = -0.0386001 -0.262654 
Iteration     1

---------------- CAUCHY entered-------------------

There are 1  breakpoints

Piece      1 f1, f2 at start point -7.0477e-02  1.0034e+00
Distance to the next break point =   5.9303e-01
Distance to the stationary point =   7.0235e-02

GCP found in this segment
Piece      1 f1, f2 at start point -7.0477e-02  1.0034e+00
Distance to the stationary point =   7.0235e-02
Cauchy X =  -97.6082 0.762686 

---------------- exit CAUCHY----------------------

Variable 2 enters the set of free variables
0 variables leave; 1 variables enter
2  variables are free at GCP on iteration 2
fn(x) = -1011.13625115823
fn(x) = -1011.13621599253
fn(x) = -1011.13628633036
fn(x) = -1011.13637260882
fn(x) = -1011.13615037747
LINE SEARCH 0 times; norm of step = 0.0200047
X = -97.604 0.762982 
G = -0.0351689 0.111116 
Iteration     2

---------------- CAUCHY entered-------------------

There are 1  breakpoints

Piece      1 f1, f2 at start point -1.3584e-02  3.5138e-01
Distance to the next break point =   5.9666e+00
Distance to the stationary point =   3.8658e-02

GCP found in this segment
Piece      1 f1, f2 at start point -1.3584e-02  3.5138e-01
Distance to the stationary point =   3.8658e-02
Cauchy X =  -97.6026 0.758687 

---------------- exit CAUCHY----------------------

2  variables are free at GCP on iteration 3
fn(x) = -1011.13594864572
fn(x) = -1011.13591260688
fn(x) = -1011.13598469101
fn(x) = -1011.13596908467
fn(x) = -1011.13594855539
LINE SEARCH 0 times; norm of step = 0.00491789
X = -97.6038 0.758066 
G = -0.0360421 0.0102646 
Iteration     3

---------------- CAUCHY entered-------------------

There are 1  breakpoints

Piece      1 f1, f2 at start point -1.4044e-03  2.3144e-02
Distance to the next break point =   6.4110e+01
Distance to the stationary point =   6.0680e-02

GCP found in this segment
Piece      1 f1, f2 at start point -1.4044e-03  2.3144e-02
Distance to the stationary point =   6.0680e-02
Cauchy X =  -97.6016 0.757443 

---------------- exit CAUCHY----------------------

2  variables are free at GCP on iteration 4
fn(x) = -1011.13586644178
fn(x) = -1011.13583031548
fn(x) = -1011.13590257453
fn(x) = -1011.13587570263
fn(x) = -1011.13587748306
fn(x) = -1011.13559884323
fn(x) = -1011.13556236587
fn(x) = -1011.13563532705
fn(x) = -1011.13556366684
fn(x) = -1011.13565411881
LINE SEARCH 1 times; norm of step = 0.0113825
X = -97.5928 0.755225 
G = -0.0364806 -0.045226 
Iteration     4

---------------- CAUCHY entered-------------------

There are 1  breakpoints

Piece      1 f1, f2 at start point -3.3762e-03  9.9264e-02
Distance to the next break point =   3.2011e+00
Distance to the stationary point =   3.4013e-02

GCP found in this segment
Piece      1 f1, f2 at start point -3.3762e-03  9.9264e-02
Distance to the stationary point =   3.4013e-02
Cauchy X =  -97.5916 0.756763 

---------------- exit CAUCHY----------------------

2  variables are free at GCP on iteration 5
fn(x) = -1011.13426710745
fn(x) = -1011.13422998851
fn(x) = -1011.13430423286
fn(x) = -1011.13413514306
fn(x) = -1011.1344185813
LINE SEARCH 0 times; norm of step = 0.050036
X = -97.543 0.749901 
G = -0.0371222 -0.141719 
Iteration     5

---------------- CAUCHY entered-------------------

There are 1  breakpoints

Piece      1 f1, f2 at start point -2.1462e-02  1.1981e+00
Distance to the next break point =   1.0591e+00
Distance to the stationary point =   1.7914e-02

GCP found in this segment
Piece      1 f1, f2 at start point -2.1462e-02  1.1981e+00
Distance to the stationary point =   1.7914e-02
Cauchy X =  -97.5424 0.75244 

---------------- exit CAUCHY----------------------

2  variables are free at GCP on iteration 6
fn(x) = -1011.12956042056
fn(x) = -1011.12952230999
fn(x) = -1011.12959853766
fn(x) = -1011.12922961823
fn(x) = -1011.12990876677
LINE SEARCH 0 times; norm of step = 0.207495
X = -97.3359 0.737203 
G = -0.0381138 -0.339574 
Iteration     6

---------------- CAUCHY entered-------------------

There are 1  breakpoints

Piece      1 f1, f2 at start point -1.1676e-01  8.2618e+00
Distance to the next break point =   4.7942e-01
Distance to the stationary point =   1.4133e-02

GCP found in this segment
Piece      1 f1, f2 at start point -1.1676e-01  8.2618e+00
Distance to the stationary point =   1.4133e-02
Cauchy X =  -97.3354 0.742002 

---------------- exit CAUCHY----------------------

2  variables are free at GCP on iteration 7
fn(x) = -1011.11857268425
fn(x) = -1011.11853415094
fn(x) = -1011.11861122416
fn(x) = -1011.11802112504
fn(x) = -1011.11913723885
LINE SEARCH 0 times; norm of step = 0.534997
X = -96.8013 0.716421 
G = -0.0385366 -0.558057 
Iteration     7

---------------- CAUCHY entered-------------------

There are 1  breakpoints

Piece      1 f1, f2 at start point -3.1291e-01  2.2910e+01
Distance to the next break point =   3.2896e-01
Distance to the stationary point =   1.3659e-02

GCP found in this segment
Piece      1 f1, f2 at start point -3.1291e-01  2.2910e+01
Distance to the stationary point =   1.3659e-02
Cauchy X =  -96.8008 0.724043 

---------------- exit CAUCHY----------------------

2  variables are free at GCP on iteration 8
fn(x) = -1011.08672288395
fn(x) = -1011.08668610505
fn(x) = -1011.08675966963
fn(x) = -1011.08616387324
fn(x) = -1011.08728243604
fn(x) = -1010.65071569386
fn(x) = -1010.65068924638
fn(x) = -1010.65074214893
fn(x) = -1010.65489832658
fn(x) = -1010.64649946224
fn(x) = -1005.86649729497
fn(x) = -1005.86654265939
fn(x) = -1005.86645194085
fn(x) = -1005.8857807846
fn(x) = -1005.86649729497
LINE SEARCH 2 times; norm of step = 21.7145
X = -75.0956 0.1 
G = 0.0453593 19.2835 
ys=-1.041e+01  -gs= 4.925e-01, BFGS update SKIPPED
Iteration     8

---------------- CAUCHY entered-------------------

There are 0  breakpoints

GCP found in this segment
Piece      1 f1, f2 at start point -2.0575e-03  1.9336e-04
Distance to the stationary point =   1.0640e+01
Cauchy X =  -75.5783 0.1 

---------------- exit CAUCHY----------------------

Variable 2 leaves the set of free variables
1  variables are free at GCP on iteration 9
fn(x) = -1005.8458046869
fn(x) = -1005.84584507957
fn(x) = -1005.84576430454
fn(x) = -1005.86504146945
fn(x) = -1005.8458046869
LINE SEARCH 0 times; norm of step = 0.482645
X = -75.5783 0.1 
G = 0.0403875 19.2368 
Iteration     9

---------------- CAUCHY entered-------------------

There are 0  breakpoints

GCP found in this segment
Piece      1 f1, f2 at start point -1.6312e-03  1.6803e-05
Distance to the stationary point =   9.7077e+01
Cauchy X =  -79.499 0.1 

---------------- exit CAUCHY----------------------

0 variables leave; 0 variables enter
1  variables are free at GCP on iteration 10
fn(x) = -1005.76663081629
fn(x) = -1005.76663082144
fn(x) = -1005.76663082144
fn(x) = -1005.7854074158
fn(x) = -1005.76663081629
LINE SEARCH 0 times; norm of step = 3.92071
X = -79.499 0.1 
G = 0 18.7766 
Iteration    10

---------------- CAUCHY entered-------------------

There are 0  breakpoints

GCP found in this segment
Piece      1 f1, f2 at start point  0.0000e+00 -0.0000e+00
Distance to the stationary point =          nan
Cauchy X =  nan nan 

---------------- exit CAUCHY----------------------

0 variables leave; 0 variables enter
1  variables are free at GCP on iteration 11
Error in optim(par = par.init, fn = logL, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = ll,  : 
  non-finite value supplied by optim
```

`Distance to the stationary point = nan` seems to be the culprit. It seems to be related to the infinite boundary of the first parameter. Making the boundary finite never results in the above error.

I don't understand L-BFGS-B well enough to qualify this as a bug or not. Maybe someone can? Furthermore I thought it would be good to leave the question and solution (i.e. making infinite boundaries finite) so other people can find it (since I already spent quite some time figuring out what the problem might be).

My R version for reference:

```
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          5.2                         
year           2018                        
month          12                          
day            20                          
svn rev        75870                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
nickname       Eggshell Igloo
```

Comment: A reproducible example could help.